# Buttons ar not gravitating towards center of a linear layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have this layout.xml, I change the "layout_gravity" atribute for the buttons but no matter what value do I assign both buttons are placed to the left of the linearlayout container. I want them to be center-justified (the comments are for pedagogic reasons, but I placed them just in case they might be the problem) :

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--root element must specify the Android resource XML namespace -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/question_text"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/false_button"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
    <!--The XML elements :: <string name="false_button">False</string>
        will have to be defined in strings.xml-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should accept any answer which you found helpful so that other Googler also get benefit of it.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following layout. I edited `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` to second `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- root element must specify the Android resource XML namespace -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="Question" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="True" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="False" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Explanation**

First `LinearLayout` has `gravity=center`. Right. It will center its children. Absolutely Right. But second `LinearLayout` is also centered but its again a holder. So it has its own properties. Though second layout's parent layout has `gravity=center`, **it will be only applied to its immediate child. Not child's child.** So, you have to again declare any other attributes once again to apply to its children.

Comment: Not sure why this works, but it does. My thinking was that gravity attribute of the parent should not affect the gravity of the children (IN THIS CASE). But now that I think about it ... could you provide an explanation why it works? Thanks

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius sure. I have edited my answer. Please review. and please accept the answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: from the explanation it seems that the attributes are being inherited by immediate children from immediate parents. I thought the attributes apply to the elements that declare them and not to the children and parents. This is confusing. Could you clarify whether I'm correct?

Comment: What we called attributes are rules actually. So you are applying rules on views. Those views have their own property. So any rule which is applied to him, also affects his children. Its parent child relationship as it can be proved by "ScrollView" which can holds only single child. So, its parent-child relationship. I can give you a demo layout if you require to clarify your doubt :)

Comment: @ChintanRathod please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320044/how-to-handle-onback-press-in-fragment-android?noredirect=1#comment33923440_22320044

Answer (score 1):

Just change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in your internal `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="@string/question_text"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Again, it would be realy helpful if you provided a short explanation, not just a quick fix on why this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this using **android:layout_weight** as follows...

```
<!-- root element must specify the Android resource XML namespace -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/question_text" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/true_button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/false_button" />
    <!--
    The XML elements :: <string name="false_button">False</string>
    will have to be defined in strings.xml
    -->

</LinearLayout>
```