# How to Handle onBack Press in Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 Fragments in my application like `HomePage , Frag1 ,Frag2,Frag3,Frag4.`

So what is happening i have used navigation drawer in my application .On the home page i have a grid view that have the link of all the four fragments.
If the user navigates from `Homepage -> Frag1 -> Frag1.2 ->Frag1.3 ->HomePage.`

So onBack press i want to show the previous fragments but once the user in on the Home Page and if he press the back i want to close my application.I am not getting the way how we can do this.

This is how i am calling the Fragments from the **Navigation Drawer**:

```
protected void getUrl(int position) {
        FragmentTransaction fragTran = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, dashboardFragment);
            fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            // fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
            fragTran.commit();
            break;
        case 1:

            if (CommonUtils.isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
                fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag1);
                fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
                fragTran.commit();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case 2:

            if (CommonUtils.isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
                fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag2);
                fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
                fragTran.commit();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (CommonUtils.isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
                fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag3);
                fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
                fragTran.commit();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            break;



        default:
            // return "";
        }
    }
```

This is how i am calling from the **GridView onClick :**

```
final FragmentTransaction fragTran = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                if (DASHBOARD_LINKS[arg2].equals("frag1")) {
                    if (CommonUtils.isNetworkConnected(getActivity())) {
                        fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame,
                                frag1);
                        fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                        fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragTran.commit();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Network Connection",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                if (DASHBOARD_LINKS[arg2].equals("frag2")) {
                    fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag2);
                    fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragTran.commit();
                }
                if (DASHBOARD_LINKS[arg2].equals("frag3")) {
                    fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag3);
                    fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragTran.commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you adding fragments to back stack ?

if no, then you can check if drawerlayout is visible then hide it and if not visible then close the application.

Comment: i have posted the complete still u r asking Are you adding fragments to back stack

Comment: OKey, so you are not adding in backstack.
then follow the steps as I mentioned.

Comment: Is **HomePage** your Fragment or Activity???

Comment: @PoojaDubey I had same problem. R u there?

Comment: Hi, I created one repo to demonstrate the solution. Please check. https://github.com/rathodchintan/Fragment-Back-Stack

Comment: @ChintanRathod thanks for this this is quite simple example how we can handle back press in fragment

Comment: @PoojaDubey Hey where are you??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add your fragments like this:

```
int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, dashboardFragment)
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
        .addToBackStack(String.valueOf(count))
        .commit();
```

Then, when you click on your grid, just add them as shown above. But if you click on item in nav drawer, do this before:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("0", 0); // "0" here is a tag of transaction you added before. "0" is for first added fragment (your home fragment, I assume). You can pop back stack to second with "1", if you like
```

This will clear the memory of previous fragments and you will not go back to them on "back" pressed.

And finally, implement this in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() <= 1) {
        finish();      
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

This will finish your app if you are in your first home fragment.

Comment: In case 0 i am putting your first code to get count then i am getting fragmentManager cannot be resolved...

Comment: fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentTransaction to android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction on this line fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); i am using as u see in the getURL function getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: well, sorry, I missed that, use getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Please make clear for fragmentManager what i have to do first in the code

Comment: i am using these imports import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

Comment: Well with all respect, I submitted an approach to do what you want, minor details is up to you. I assure you this will work for your needs, you just have to spend some time to tie it up.

Comment: the first way of calling will be done on the click of GridView right i am getting confused in the words .i am doing right or not

Comment: You perform the code from the first snippet every time you add a fragment. When you click on your nav drawer, you perform second snippet + first snippet. When you click on grid, just first snippet.

Comment: This is really awesome it working great as of now .Thanks for the great help.If i get any issue in future hope you will help me again on this issue ...!!!!!!!

Comment: For bounty you have to wait for 20 hrs then only i can do this

Comment: i am sorry i was on leave and i forgot .i have just did that

Comment: @Dmide Hello r u there dude?

Comment: "Then, when you click on your grid, just add them as shown above. But if you click on item in nav drawer, do this before:" what is means?

Comment: Hi. It means perform popBackStackImmediate() before a transaction

Comment: @Dmide I have tried but it is not working as your explanation.

Comment: @Dmide I have called fragment from navigation drawer and after that call another fragment from that fragment on list item click so i have made changes same as you have said. but it's not working what i want.

Answer (score 2):

Just Use addToBackStack(null);

```
 fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, dashboardFragment);
        fragTran.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
         fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
        fragTran.commit();
```

So once you add new fragment with addToBackStack(null) It will save instance into memory and on back press it will pops up current fragment and load previous one.

Comment: Hey, No need to do these thing. If you just want to go to previous Fragment just use fragmentmanage.addToBackstack(null); This will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: see i want to show the previous history but once the user is on  the home page if he presses the back btn i want to close the app

Comment: So you don't want to close application when user press back on Home page (First Fragment) right?

Comment: See there are two ways to navigate in my app.First from the GridView and second from the Navigation Drawer.
If user click on the Gridview frag1 in that i have multiple inner frags like frag1->frag1.2->frag1.3 so on here if he press the home button from the Navigation drawer it will come to the home page.So now if he presses back the app need to be closed but what is happeing it is shwowing the farg1.3->fra1.2->frag1

Comment: i hope you got what i am trying to say

Comment: Do one thing. Add all fragment using one TAG. And execute following code in Home button press:       int i = 1;
    while(i > 0){
     Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DETAIL_FRAGMENT);
     if(fragment != null)
      i = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
     else
      i = -1;
    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49457/discussion-between-pooja-dubey-and-yashdeep-patel)

Comment: Can u please see the chat once

Comment: yes i have tried the code that u have mentioned in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can set static flag for each fragment class separately.& on backpress of fragment check value for flag in Fragment Activity. & according to that call backpress method of fragment class for performing operations